# Iterate all records in databases into a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

So, I have 3 tables in a database:

In **doctor** table:

```
id (PK)
doctor_name
```

In **patient** table:

```
id (PK)
patient_name
patient_unit
patient_doctor_id (FK)
```

In **report** table:

```
id (PK)
report_issue
report_result
report_patient_id (FK)
```

As you can see **patient** takes **doctor**'s id as a foreign key, and **report** takes **patient**'s id as a foreign key.

So, a doctor have many patients, and a patient have many reports.

What I wanna do is to display all these tables into an HTML table, by using the foreign keys as a reference to respective names, and reports.

How do I iterate these records in the database to display it in a table? What MySQL query do I use in this case?

Comment: Check this [visual explanation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) of JOINS

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM DOCTOR

LEFT JOIN PATIENT
ON (DOCTOR.ID = PATIENT.PATIENT_DOCTOR_ID)

LEFT JOIN REPORT
ON (PATIENT.ID = REPORT.REPORT_PATIENT_ID)
```

And if you want a specific report add this condition at the end:

```
WHERE REPORT.ID = REPORT_NUMBER
```

Saludos.